# How isolated are Windows and Wubi-Ubuntu installations?

Tags: windows, wubi, malware

If I install Ubuntu via Wubi, I would like to still use Windows for many things, like playing some games not available on Ubuntu.

While using Ubuntu, **if I encountered an executable that would normally infect Windows, would anything happen to the host Windows operating system?**

Would Windows have the virus that I downloaded, or **are the two operating systems completely separated?**

Another thing: **Are files saved in Windows openable from Ubuntu and files saved in Ubuntu are openable from Windows?**

Comment: This question can't really be answered as it is written. Can you look at the FAQ page and then try to edit it please? Also, dual-booting works far better than wubi and will prevent a Windows infection from affecting your Ubuntu partition.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! **Please ask only *one question* per question!** Also take a look at the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> If using Ubuntu, I enter to a page which would infect Windows, if next time I enter using Windows, is going to happen anything to Windows?

No, this won't happen.

> More easy, if I see a page which using windows would download a virus but i'd chosen ubuntu that time, when i use again windows, will it have the virus I downloaded?

If you download a virus on Windows it stays on Windows, it doesn't carry over to Ubuntu. If you switch to Ubuntu and switch back to Windows, Ubuntu doesn't fix your Windows viruses, it stays on Windows.

> files saved in windows, are openable from ubuntu and files saved in ubuntu are openabled from windows?

Yes, you can open files in both fine.

I'm not sure what the strange code is.

Comment: escuse me, as i don't speak english very well, it is hard to me to express myself. It apears the black screen with grey letters to choose ubuntu or windows, it enters to another one similar, buy it has phrases I don't understand and it writes things alone. it's like, I say it in spanish and how I thinks it's called in english the "codigo del sistema" I think it's called System Code or something like that. Is it normal?

Comment: **@nick**: That seems like a separate question, which you should [ask separately](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). **Vadi**: Windows does not have the ability to see files inside a Wubi system, without added software.

Comment: @nick Your English is great. It might help to try browsing using Google Translate, which will [translate entire web pages](http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?act=url&hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=auto&tl=es&u=http://askubuntu.com/questions/154809/how-isolated-are-windows-and-wubi-ubuntu-installations&usg=ALkJrhh_gEA6f-LSX0NINNiu-k3QaAlkJw) for you.